# Django, How to filter context output from HTML template?

Tags: django

I have a ListView that sends context as `news` in the HTML template.

The below code is supposed to slice the context array from the 4th element to until its end

```
{% for post in news[4:0] %}
............
{% endfor %}
```

But following error occurs

Could not parse the remainder: '[4:]' from 'news[4:]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the slice template tag:

```
{% for post in news|slice:"4:" %}
............
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this inside your ListView by overriding the context data like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['last_4_news_items'] = News.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:4]
    return context
```

template:

```
{% for news in last_4_news_items %}
    {{ news }}
{% endfor %}
```